# Stack Apps graph time filters make pretty much no sense

Tags: bug, status-completed

When viewing the Query Statistics graphs for an application, you have the option of choosing 'Week', 'Month', 'Year', or 'All Time'.

When hovering over 'week' it states "view stats for the last 7 days", 'month' states "view stats for the last 30 days".

I've never been able to view less than 3 months at a time. As a matter of fact, the 'week' and 'month' tabs for my app appear to show the same information, no difference in granularity either.

[image: API Queries per Week]

[image: API Queries per Month]

The year tab appears correct.

I may need to write this up as a separate issue, but X-axis labels may also sometimes just be wrong. Consider this graph of the misc queries by week:

[image: Misc queries per Week]

Half a query?

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed in a recent deploy, there were some errors calculating date ranges for those queries.

As to "half a query"-type stuff, if there's literally no data for a day (which *can* happen, gathering query stats is sort of a "best effort" thing; it's rather rare though) our graph library will just interpolate.  This can look a little odd.

Note that you can also download the whole data set.

[image]